# I think [trackpad] and [touchpad] should be tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The description for [trackpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/trackpad) is:

> an input device commonly found on laptops, used in place of a mouse. Also called a touchpad.

And the description for [touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) is:

> Questions related to the configuration and activation of touchpad/trackpads.

The two tags pretty much refer to the exact same thing, and so I think it makes sense to make those two tags synonyms.

Comment: Never mind. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They already are [synonyms](https://askubuntu.com/tags/touchpad/synonyms)

Technically trackpads and touchpads are two different things that serve a similar function.

https://anydifferencebetween.com/difference-between-touchpad-and-trackpad/

[image: Image of a trackpad next to a laptop with a touchpad]

I think the tag descriptions should get altered to reflect that, I don't think they are synonyms personally but trackpad has so little use, it probably makes no difference.